# Need help logging into remote computer and reading text file

Tags: c#, networking

I have created a windows forms application which I want to use to connect to a remote computer and display
data stored in a text file. However, when it attempts to connect to the remote computer I get the following error:

**The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)**

The code I am using to connect to the remote computer:

```
 var conOpt = new ConnectionOptions();
        conOpt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        conOpt.EnablePrivileges = true;
        conOpt.Username = "username";
        conOpt.Password = "password";
        var scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", "computername"), conOpt );

        scope.Connect();
```

After researching this on the net, it seems that the application may not be
 allowed to connect because of firewall settings on the server or related to ports. Or perhaps I'm missing something in the code?

Could this be related to the group policy on the remote computer to
 allow specific applications to connect? What else needs to be taken into account in terms of configuration? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Make sure that the RPC service is running on your remote machine `net start rpcss`

Comment: it looks like could be better done with some scriptong language and ssh rather than C#

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The RPC service is running on the remove machine. A win forms application is needed because it will also do other things but I want to first make it do something simple like reading a file on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the remote machine on a domain? If so, consider including that in `ConnectionOptions`:

```
conOpt.Authority = string.Format("ntlmdomain:{0}", domainName);
```

Also, try using a `SecureString` for the `SecurePassword` property instead of a regular string. Don't think it matters, but is worth a shot. This is how you create a `SecureString`:

```
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

foreach (char character in password)
{
     secureString.AppendChar(character);
}

conOpt.SecurePassword = secureString;
```

As you mentioned, it's possible that the firewall is blocking the connection, although `RPC` connections *usually* aren't blocked on local networks (unless configured otherwise). Also, to add to paqogomez's comment regarding services, make sure the **Remote Procedure Call (RPC)** (or **Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator** if using XP or Windows Server 2003) is running.

Comment: The RPC Locator service is running on the remote computer. Is there any other way of doing this other than using WMI classes? Is there any configuration of firewall on the remote computer that should be setup?

Comment: Well another option would be to create a `WCF` service and host it on the remote machine, and have a that service send the text file to the client(s). But without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve by this, I would say this is probably not the best way.